# What is a "stitch-and-glue" kayak?

Tags: kayaks

I decided to kill some time today and look at pictures of wooden kayaks online. I kept seeing the phrase "stitch-and-glue" with respect to some of the kayaks. What does this term mean?

Comment: Great way to kill time! Kayaks are awesome!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A stitch and glue boat hull is made of plywood panels assembled with fiberglass tape. Contrary to traditional boat building in which molds define the hull shape, in stitch and glue, **the hull panels define the shape**.

Another major difference with wooden boat building is that **the framing of a stitch and glue boat is made of fiberglass**.